# data type which can be used to store data according to the arrival for the session

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

> I want to know what are the data types which can be used to store data according to the arrival of the session.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Question asked is very ambiguous, my interpretation is that
there are two functions:

1. Adds a new session time.
2. Check if a particular session time is already seen or not.

**1st Approach:** Using a hash-set where the time-complexity for both imputing a session-time and checking for a session time is `O(1)`.
**Cons:** The space complexity is `O(N)`. Since we are storing each session time independently the storage needed will be huge, assuming for large input data.
i.e. if session time is `{1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10}` we will be storing each of this numbers in hash-set differently.

**2nd Approach:** Use an ordered map to store range of session time which are already seen. **Key** for start time of the range and **Value** for ending time of the range
Using the same eg. `{1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10}` will be stored as:

```
| Key      | Value |
| -------- | ------|
| 1        | 4     |
| 6        | 10    |
```

This way we are decreasing storage space, and it's easier to search for ranges.

**Cons:** The insertion and checking time are both `O(logN)`.

You can use any approach as per your requirement:

- 1st Approach is better if you need to tell if a session time is see or not.
- 2nd Approach is better if you need to return what the missing sessions are to have all sessions between any two times **T1** and **T2**.